# Looping and Recording columns in Filtered Table if one cell follows condition

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filter, excel-tables

I have difficulties with looping through my table when there is a filter (something I want since I have to filter first and then run the macro on the remaining cells).

Let's say table mainly contains empty cells and few "x" randomly distributed. I want to record the column headers if and only if there is at least one "x" in the column and skip the other column.
My macro work when there is no filter applied. I think I also have issues with empty cells when I set the column range.

Do you have any adivce?

```
Sub Filtre()

Dim CategoryName() As String
Dim NumberCategory As Integer
NumberCategory = 0

Dim CategoryCell As Range
Dim TopCell As Range
Dim CategoryRange As Range
Dim ObjectNumber As Integer
Dim intValueToFind As String
Dim TableObject As ListObject
Dim Rng As Range
Dim TableCell As Range

    Set TableObject = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_objet")
    Set TopCell = TableObject.HeaderRowRange.Find("AC1")
    Set CategoryRange = Range(TopCell, TopCell.End(xlToRight))
    ObjectNumber = TableObject.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

    intValueToFind = "x"

For Each CategoryCell In CategoryRange

            CategoryCell.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
            Set Rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            For Each TableCell In Rng
                If TableCell.Value = intValueToFind Then
                    NumberCategory = NumberCategory + 1
                    ReDim Preserve CategoryName(NumberCategory - 1)
                    CategoryName(NumberCategory - 1) = CategoryCell.Value
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next TableCell
        Next CategoryCell

Dim msg As String

Dim i As Integer
    msg = "Category in array: " & vbCrLf
    For i = 1 To NumberCategory
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & CategoryName(i - 1)
    Next i
MsgBox msg
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Rather than using filters I'd recommend looping on the columns and using the `Range.Find` method to return a range. If the range is not nothing there is an x present in the column `if not foundRange is nothing then`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I finally found a simple solution to my problem. I copied the visible cells to a new worksheet and then applied my modified code to this simple table without filters.

Comment: Yet, I encountered another strange thing. When there is no filter applied to the initial table, the new copy/pasted cells keep an excel table format. But when a filter is applied to the initial table, the cells are not pasted as a table. Do you know why ? I used : ws.ListObjects("Ref").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=ws_temp.Range("A1")